# Angular If statement- check route

Tags: angular, typescript, path, routes

I want to do an if-statement for my program to check on which route/ path I'm currently on.

I have a function and this function should only work when I'm on a specific path.
For example:
If the path is homepage I'm on the "homepage", but if I write "homepage/add" in the url, I want to call a function.
I tried "
if(this.router.url.include('add') { .... code ... } but It didn't work.
Could someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add nested route '/**add**' and then in this component which will be available for '**add**' route - call your function on `ngOnInit(){ /// }`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'homepage',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'add', component: DashboardAddComponent}
    ]
  }
]
```

then in component:

```
class DashboardAddComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    // ... CALL HERE
  }
}
```